# Switch Scrolling between child (ListView) & parent (Container)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to implement a scroll effect similar to Google Maps application. Basically, my hierarchy looks like:

```
Stack   
    child#1 : Container with Scroll-able Text (as background) covers screen height.   
    child#2 : Container drag-able vertically (size=screen height & sits close to the bottom e.g. top: screen-height
- 50)
       child of child#2: ListView
```

Now, if the user starts dragging from bottom to top, the child#2 start to move up and start to cover more and more of child#1 and goes up to the top of the screen, will the whole of child#1 is covered. If the user keeps on dragging up, the ListView should start to scroll up.

I have tried using SliverList from Flutter, but for one thing, I don't want the header that comes with it and secondly, I want to have the child#1 scroll able (as long as it's not covered by child#2).

I am thinking to have initially the ListView non scroll-able and once the child#2 reaches the top, switch the ListView to scrollable by capturing the ScrollNoticiations. Though I am not sure if that's feasible solution.

Is there any better way to implementing the same effect?

Thanks!